# Why is having multiple college majors seen as a bad thing when applying to graduate school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, major, minor

I have been told that triple (or more) majoring and/or taking numerous minors is seen as a bad quality when applying to graduate school. Can anybody explain we why they do not want academically oriented students that like to learn stuff?

Comment: *why they do not want academically oriented students that like to learn stuff* That's pretty tendentious, dude.

Comment: `*Tendentious*: expressing or intending to promote a particular cause or point of view, especially a controversial one.` (in case you didn't know, I didn't) cool word

Comment: It can often be that liking to learn stuff is actually detrimental to doing research.  I remember a friend that finished a PhD but found the experience something of an ordeal telling me, "I discovered I liked reading about beautiful theories in books but not actually creating my own, messy theory."

Comment: You can ask people who have already been there. I think most of them will tell you that it's not a good thing. I had a double major in my undergraduate era, and whenever someone asks my guidance on taking a double major, I strongly discourage him. Because I think you are more likely to reach water by digging a 30-meters deep well, than by digging two 5-meters deep holes.

Answer (score 98):

It seems to be a common fallacy among undergraduate students that completing more majors and/or minors means that you have learned more in college.  I think this comes from the mistaken belief that completing the coursework required for a major in a subject means that you have mastered the subject.

In actuality, the coursework required for a major in a subject should be viewed as the *minimum* amount of coursework necessary to be able to claim *any* expertise in the subject.  If your goal is to study a subject at the graduate level, you typically want to take many additional undergraduate courses in the field beyond those required for a degree before you can reasonably begin graduate work.  Graduate schools look for this sort of deep experience in potential applicants, and tend to frown on those who have completed only the minimum requirements for a major.

So graduate schools don't see extra majors and minors as bad, exactly.  But if you spend time completing lots of extra majors and minors you probably won't have enough time to develop the expertise in your primary subject that you need for graduate school.  Instead of taking on a third major, you should plan to take roughly six extra courses in your primary field.  This might seem like it doesn't accomplish anything since it doesn't help you satisfy any official requirement, but it's exactly the sort of coursework that graduate schools are looking for.

Comment: So, I'm being encouraged to spend at least a few thousand more and spending 18 more credit hours in classes I don't need just to get a shot at graduate-level work? Further, in the US school that I attended, those six extra classes would be mid-high level, so it would require at least an additional semester to accomplish. That doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: @GGMG: I don't think he's saying you should spend extra time as an undergrad just to get into grad school.  He's saying that, with the electives you already need to take anyway, it's better to spend most of them on advanced classes in your major rather than picking up an extra major or a minor.

Comment: @GGMC - Exactly what Henry said. Instead of taking classes for that third major, take more electives related to your first major/minor. In the end, it's the same number of classes, but different focus. You can spend your time going wide or deep, and since graduate study is primarily about going deep, you may be better off focusing on a more limited subject area.

Comment: Okay, I understand. My apologies, the undergraduate school I attended worked differently and split the classes strictly into "Classes related to your major" and "Classes not related to your major." If you wanted more classes related to your major, you had to pay extra.

Comment: @GGMG [Relevant](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1212/820). Welcome to Academia SE!

Comment: I disagree with "the coursework required for a major in a subject should be viewed as the minimum amount of coursework necessary to be able to claim any expertise in the subject".  Coursework is not the only way to gain expertise and is probably not the best way.  Many experts are not college graduates.

Comment: @emory That's a fair point, but the context of this question is to help a beginning college student plan their coursework.  For the most part, the way that undergraduate college students gain expertise in subjects is by taking courses.

Comment: @emory Also, this is in the context of a graduate school application, where in many cases coursework is the best indicator of expertise the grad school is going to get (obviously depending on what the major is and where the application is going).

Comment: @GGMG I'd quibble with the claim that you don't need the 6 extra classes. They may not be required to claim an undergraduate level qualification, but you will almost certainly have to learn much of the same material anyway in the process of doing your graduate work. Having a guide to take you through what's still fairly basic knowledge in your focus can make the process much faster and easier.

Comment: What if my university (and department in it) is small and doesn't offer enough extra courses?  I took every class available to me in my major except the intro class I tested out of, and the two every-other-year classes I was abroad for.  Should I have missed out on the amazing opportunity and experience of studying abroad for a better chance at grad school?

Comment: @senschen: To your first question, it means you're at a disadvantage in grad school applications (though a smaller one than if those courses were available and you didn't take them). Your second question seems strange; Jim isn't saying people *should* give up all other opportunities for marginal benefits at getting into grad school, he's pointing out how those decisions will affect their chances. (And, surely, people should make those decisions aware of that impact.)

Comment: @Henry  How do they know what classes were available? Do they really look that info up for every applicant? The second bit is what I was really confused about, though, because that was how I read the answer-- like, if I really wanted to go to grad school, I shouldn't have taken my other majors and I should have taken all three of those other classes to make some extra credits in the field. Which didn't seem right to me-- like its saying that I can't possibly be passionate about more than one field. I wish I'd read this question/answer in my first semester. Things might have gone differently.

Comment: As an addendum to what was already suggested here, make sure you take as many courses as possible in the given subject you want to pursue **which are cross-listed as (post-)graduate-level courses**: There is a world of difference between bog-standard undergraduate courses and (post-)graduate-level ones, and the former are often more or less seen as fluff.

Comment: @senschen I'm being brief; this is a lot to answer in comments. Most grad school admits have taken significantly more than the minimum number of upper level courses in their major (or closely related majors). More is a plus, none is a minus. If a student is close to getting in, coming from a school without many courses is a mitigating factor; they can probably tell just from knowing about the school, but might look up the website if needed. It's also might get pointed out in a recommendation letter; faculty at small schools with success getting people into grad school know about these issues.

Comment: @senschen These are small effects, and there are other factors: a _related_ double major can be a plus, other things can make up for weak course work, etc. It’s not counting credits, it’s looking at what you’ve learned; the intro class you skipped wouldn’t have mattered, two more upper level courses might have on the margin. It’s not at all like saying you can't be passionate about more than one field; grad admissions is not a holistic evaluation of you as a person. The committee is looking for evidence you’ll do well in grad school, and courses in your major are a good source of evidence.

Comment: So, it basically transmits the message that you are a *"jack of all trades, master of none"*, which is frowned upon in academia.

Comment: @vsz People always forget the rest of that saying: *jack of all trades, master of none, but better than master of one*.  Obviously academia doesn't agree, but still.

Comment: "spend at least a few thousand more and spending 18 more credit hours in classes I don't need"  This is a terrible point of view ... if you are truly interested in graduate level courses taking these classes shouldn't be a "need" but rather a "want" ... if you are just ticking off the boxes for another expensive piece of paper ... you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 40):

> Can anybody explain we why they do not want academically oriented students that like to learn stuff

Jim Belk basically answered this, but I want to point out this line, because the implicit assumption here is wrong.  Taking an extra major or a minor isn't the only way to express being academically oriented; choosing courses involves a trade-off between breadth - taking courses in a lot of subject - and depth - taking more and more advanced courses in a single subject.  An academically oriented student might find either appealing (and most have at least some inclination in both directions and have to make hard choices).

An unfortunate consequence of the way most multiple major/minor programs is that they incentivize breadth by giving students tangible recognition for it.  Unfortunately, if instead of taking extra courses in a different subject to get another major, you take a bunch of advanced courses in your only major, you're learning just as much, but you don't get a certificate to show that.

But grad schools typically prefer depth, because that's what you do in grad school - delving to the frontier of research in a single subject - and beginning that process as an undergrad both shows the right attitude and gives you a head start.

Comment: This is 100% right. Having too many majors/minors is seen as a lack of focus, which isn't ideal for grad school.

Answer (score 27):

One possible exception to this general perception would be research areas that are intrinsically interdisciplinary.  There are niche positions in both research and industry where people who can 'translate' between normally quite distinct disciplines and assist with integrating across them are highly valued.  I've seen this particularly in engineering, but there are potentially some interesting crossovers in even things like philosophy with neurology or mathematics with history.  In some cases these crossovers become the seeds for entirely new fields of study, as we discover new connections and hence the possibility for new specializations.

If you do want to make this a perceived asset rather than a perceived risk, it helps if the broad degree is accompanied by a clear focus and interest in an interdisciplinary research topic that combines the areas of study.  Find out what kind of research is being done in your overlapping areas of interest and find a graduate program where this kind of research is being done.  The right spin and extracurricular background could change the impression from "professional student unsure of what to study" to "focused individual willing to pursue a challenging and unique interdisciplinary research career."

Comment: +1 for bringing this up. In my CS grad program I met a lot of students who had minored or double majored in linguistics or cogsci, to give them a better background for AI / NLP.

Comment: I definitely agree with this for double-majors and/or minors (it's a large part of why I double-majored), but I don't know of any field where triple isn't just excessive.

Comment: @BrianDHall, CS+linguistics+stats for example if aiming at AI

Answer (score 4):

Jim Belk's and Henry's answers are quite good. I certainly agree that required coursework is a minimal set of skills necessary to succeed in a field, and that depth is important to acquire and to convey. I disagree, however, with the other answers' emphasis on more advanced coursework as the way to attain depth. That's certainly fine, but I think the more important route is **research**. If I saw a graduate school application from someone with three majors but little research experience, I would wonder: "why, if this person has so smart, and has so much time, is he/she not diving into research?"

There are two reasons for this. First, research is where you really learn what contemporary science *is*, and this is quite different from coursework -- it's more difficult, more open-ended, and (in my opinion) more exciting. Second, graduate school is *about* research, and the most common "failure mode" I see among new graduate students is an inability to transition from being students to being researchers. Doing undergraduate research, and doing it well, shows that you can make this transition.

Answer (score 3):

Many uni students, especially those for whom mommy & daddy are footing the bill, often have no idea what they want to do, but they do enjoy "student life".  And so they take lots of courses in different fields, hoping something will strike their fancy while at the same time enabling them to continue to enjoy the good life without worries.

Since grad school is intensely focused, that kind of dilettantism does not impress the grad admissions people.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other excellent answers: It is often **the result of personal experience**. While it may not be statistically sound, coming up through the academic system in my country (in more than one discipline, actually; but not multi-majoring; and up to a PhD) I noticed more multi-major undergrads who are not serious about their studies and do not pursue any of their majors seriously than the other way around. Although, frankly, there's a correlation between this impression and what the majors actually are, and what major people want to continue in. So, I've not encountered many Law + Psychology majors I thought highly of relative to pure Psychologists or Lawyers/Juris Doctors. X + business for different values of X - experience has made me quite suspicious of that choice. Or, for another example, Math+CS dual-majors I've met tend to be mathematicians 'at heart' who do well in Comp Sci theory but not so well (or poorly) as effective programmers.